# Is it possible to customize the token generated by Firebase Cloud Messaging in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think the title is clear enough. How can I do that? I need to set my custom data as token to any device in FCM. is it possible? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to customize the token generated by `FCM` because it's the only way to target the device and send push notifications. I don't see any use for changing the token because if you want to exchange data between devices you can use the body of the notification to send data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM tokens (nowadays called Instance IDs) are determined by FCM, and cannot be determined by your own code.

You might want to elaborate in your question on the actual use-case, since there typically is another/better way to accomplish the goal when this comes up. Also see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)